# IIS7 crash on MSVCR100.dll

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, iis

Since this morning my w3wp process keeps crashing whenever I try to open an application on the server (IIS7.5).

This is the error as it appears in the event log:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7a5f8
Faulting module name: MSVCR100.dll, version: 10.0.40219.325, time stamp: 0x4df2be1e
Exception code: 0xc0000417
Fault offset: 0x0008af3e
Faulting process id: 0x14d0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cc5d78b3257d74
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll
Report Id: f0dcc5a8-c96b-11e0-ae82-5c260a4cea30
```

Anyone have any idea? This is quite critical for me to get it up and running again quickly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the system has worked prior to this situation, then the possible steps/approaches to consider:

1. "chkdsk c: /r" to assess and address any possible errors (it may fix the file fault, if on exists)
2. replace the MSVCR100.dll file (from backup or original installation)